# Get Xpath Value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a xml format in the below format:

```
<start>
<contents>
  <content name="content1" id="1582670184">
  <properties name="GIFT_ID" type="data" value="109"/>
  <properties name="KEY_ID" type="data" value="1006"/>
 </content>
 <content name="content2" id="1582670194">
  <properties name="GIFT_ID" type="data" value="110"/>
  <properties name="KEY_ID" type="data" value="1007"/>
 </content>
 <content name="content3" id="12346">
  <properties name="GIFT_ID" type="data" value="111"/>
 </content>
 <content name="content4" id="12345">
  <properties name="GIFT_ID" type="data" value="112"/>
 </content>
</contents>
</start>
```

I want two values from the above xml satisfying the below conditions

Case 1: How to get the name in `<content>` tag where only "GIFT_ID" is there in `<properties>` tag i.e. the content names where only "GIFT_ID" is present in the properties.

Expected output is: content3 ,content 4

Case 2: How to get the @value of GIFT_ID  for those contents where "KEY_ID" tag is not there.
Expected output is: 111,112.
Please help me how to figure out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating your descriptions into XPath...

**Case 1 :**

```
//content[properties/@name = 'GIFT_ID' and not(properties/@name != 'GIFT_ID')]/@name
```

**Case 2 :**

```
//content[not(properties/@name = 'KEY_ID')]/properties[@name = 'GIFT_ID']/@value
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I try to run the above two statements,but it is giving NO MATCH in the output.

Comment: @Mr.Singthoi what is your XPath version? Tested with both XPath 1.0 and 2.0, the above worked with either versions. Here is the demo : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/8dd5f82edd38eef66d53f690a10f5b76

Comment: @Mr.Singthoi What tool did you test with? Are you sure that you tested with _exactly_ the input XML document you show in the question? If you actually use an XPath library in a programming language, show this code, too and tag the question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks this resolves the issue.I was testing the same in http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html website with the same xml.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

Case 1:

```
//content[ count(*)=1][//content/properties [@name='GIFT_ID']]/@name
```

Case 2:

```
//content[ count(*)=1]/properties [@name='GIFT_ID']/@value
```

**Edit:**

The two statements above makes the (probably wrong) assumption that each content tag will contain at most one property named 'GIFT_ID' or 'KEY_ID' - hence the use of count(*)=1.

However, reflecting on [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1987598/mathias-m%C3%BCller)' question on why count(*)=1 is a requirements I have refined the two select statements to cater
for the case where there may be:

1. Properties with names other than 'GIFT_ID and 'KEY_ID'
2. The case where a content node contain multiple 'properies' nodes named 'GIFT_ID.

Case 1

```
//content[count(properties[not(@name='GIFT_ID')])=0 and properties [@name='GIFT_ID']]/@name
```

Case 2

```
//content[count(properties[@name='KEY_ID'])=0 and properties [@name='GIFT_ID']]/properties/@value
```

This is just an alternative to [har07](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2998271/har07) solution - his is more succinct and definitely a better solution.

Comment: Why would `count(*) =1` be a requirement?

Comment: Better now, but in this case, you should not use count at all because you do not have to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply